# SMTP azure firewall rule

Tags: azure, smtp, microsoft-office-365

this might be a newbie question, but how do you configure an Azure Firewall rule for smtp.office365.com? I’ve had a look at application rules which only support port 80 and 443, whereas smtp requires 25 or 587. We can’t add ip addresses as all the IPs I’ve added from MSFT websites don’t seem to work.

Listed here:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/enterprise/urls-and-ip-address-ranges?view=o365-worldwide

Am I missing something obvious or is it more of a complex set up than adding a rule, as the current IPs are being blocked.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide more detail. You want to connect outbound from Azure to smtp.office365.com? What do you mean "the current IPs are being blocked? What are you trying to do?

Comment: @joeqwerty hi the current IPs being blocked, where I meant that the IPs that when we try to access smtp get blocked but I’ve added the ranges that are available online, I would have expected an smtp.office365.com fqdn tag. I just need the IPs for smtp by Microsoft I guess?

Comment: What are you trying to do specifically? Are you trying to connect outbound from Azure to smtp.office365.com?

Comment: @joeqwerty hi yes sorry from our internal servers and application outbound through the azure firewall, which is where it’s getting blocked

Answer (score 0):

Port 587 is open from Azure outbound.  Port 25 is blocked outbound by default, depending on the subscription type.

Have a look at https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-network/troubleshoot-outbound-smtp-connectivity to see if it helps.

Comment: Thanks Greg, the issue seems to be that the outbound connectivity is blocked by the azure firewall, but I can’t find a list of IPs or a fqdn tag to allow traffic to the office 365 relay service we have configured? I can see the traffic getting blocked on 587 and 25, I can do open on ports 25 and 587 to any destination, but I’d like it a bit more secure?

Comment: Then your next step is to use Network Watcher to diagnose network flows (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/network-watcher-network-configuration-diagnostics-overview) and outbound VM connectivity problems (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/network-watcher/network-watcher-connectivity-overview).